# get value from jtextfield and set it to jtable in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

i using netbean gui. i donno the code is it same or not. but atleast i had a rough idea on how to do it.

i had a Jtable, textfield and a Jbutton

i wan to enter something into textfield and after clicking the button, the textfield will draw the data from database and set it to the Jtable. everytime i key in something to text field, i wan the data to be appear in Jtable. is this possible?

i already try using jtable model. but i don't know how to create proper jtable model.

Comment: There are many good tutorials on google.

Comment: Welcome in SO. First this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and second please post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Suggest you explore your netbeans IDE where UI designing is a piece of cake especially inserting jTextfield, jTable etc......using simple drag and drop.
(There's option to create a swing based java file by default where javax.swing.JFrame or similar classes are extended automatically. Insertion can be done via Design Tab.)

And about getting the functions to read from jTables and jTextfields. I suggest you to check the corresponding javadocs.